# How do I change my Scipy.Optimize.Minimize configuration to better find solution for constrained optimization?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I'm trying to do constrained optimization with `Scipy.Optimize.Minimize` and I keep on getting no solution, when I know there is a solution, because I can find one when I change the initial values to something else. But I don't want to be bound by the initial values since I'm trying to loop through a lot of optimizations over different time periods and then see the distribution of optimal solutions.  And honestly, I don't want to be too biased by what I think the solution should be.

Currently, I am using `SLSQP` as the solver method.  I've also set `maxiter` to 10000  I was wondering if there are other settings I can tweak to force the solver to run longer?

The data set itself is not large, and problem itself is not difficult.  I am trying to solve for just two variables.  The variables have bounds (must be positive or negative) and some additional constraints.  It is somewhat non-linear since it involves MIN and MAX functions.  But since the data set is small and I have time, I can afford to wait.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is 
optimize a certain function, and you're wondering if changing the optimizer configuration is a good way to go 
about it. Because your real question
is "How do I optimize my function?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As 
it is written right now, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: To be more clear, “How do I do constrained optimization of this function?” depends on the function and the constraints. Without this information, this isn’t answerable.